# How can I get the version, license, author, and dependencies for all installed Python modules in an Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, conda

I have a `conda` environment from which I would like to get information on every installed module. Preferably, most or all of the information that one would get from `pip show`, such as:

- name
- version
- license
- url (to download from/or the homepage)
- dependencies

If I do `conda list` in my environment, I get something that looks like this:

```
py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.16.5           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  3.0.0                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_2
packaging                 19.2                       py_0
pandas                    0.25.1           py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
```

which is *good* but not good enough, and while the `--json` flag adds a little extra info, it doesn't include the license, for example.

An equivalent output from `pip` which *has* the information I want is:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.16.5
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tables, statsmodels, seaborn, scikit-learn, PyWavelets, pytest-doctestplus, pytest-arraydiff, patsy, pandas, numexpr, numba, mkl-random, mkl-fft, matplotlib, imageio, h5py, Bottleneck, bokeh, bkcharts, astropy
```

I did find `conda info`/`conda search --info`, but that seems to produce information for **all** packages, not the one actually in my environment.

A snippet of that output for `numpy=1.16.5` looks like:

```
numpy 1.16.5 py36h19fb1c0_0
---------------------------
file name   : numpy-1.16.5-py36h19fb1c0_0.conda
name        : numpy
version     : 1.16.5
build       : py36h19fb1c0_0
build number: 0
size        : 49 KB
license     : BSD 3-Clause
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/numpy-1.16.5-py36h19fb1c0_0.conda
md5         : faf74044b83f4e83f434b562c498ff63
timestamp   : 2019-09-12 18:05:56 UTC
dependencies:
  - blas 1.0 mkl
  - icc_rt >=2019.0.0
  - mkl >=2019.4,<2021.0a0
  - mkl-service >=2,<3.0a0
  - mkl_fft >=1.0.6,<2.0a0
  - mkl_random >=1.0.2,<2.0a0
  - numpy-base 1.16.5 py36hc3f5095_0
  - python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
  - vc >=14.1,<15.0a0
  - vs2015_runtime >=14.16.27012,<15.0a0


numpy 1.16.5 py37h19fb1c0_0
---------------------------
file name   : numpy-1.16.5-py37h19fb1c0_0.conda
name        : numpy
version     : 1.16.5
build       : py37h19fb1c0_0
build number: 0
size        : 49 KB
license     : BSD 3-Clause
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/numpy-1.16.5-py37h19fb1c0_0.conda
md5         : 2413b7e04b3511e263a5be8077148c1c
timestamp   : 2019-09-12 18:06:41 UTC
dependencies:
  - blas 1.0 mkl
  - icc_rt >=2019.0.0
  - mkl >=2019.4,<2021.0a0
  - mkl-service >=2,<3.0a0
  - mkl_fft >=1.0.6,<2.0a0
  - mkl_random >=1.0.2,<2.0a0
  - numpy-base 1.16.5 py37hc3f5095_0
  - python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0
  - vc >=14.1,<15.0a0
  - vs2015_runtime >=14.16.27012,<15.0a0
```

And there are another half dozen or more entries for `numpy version 1.16.5, since it seems to look across all available packages that meet that version.

I'm not sure how to get this equivalent information but for *only* for the packages specifically in my env.

---

**Does `conda` even have a way to list the author & license for the specific packages installed in an environment?** If not, I can at least try to cross-reference the results of `conda list` and `conda search --info`, but I'd rather not try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, conda doesn't have a built-in way to list the author and license information for specific packages in an environment. The conda list command can give you basic details about installed packages, but it doesn't include author and license info.

To get the missing information, you can combine the output of conda list with conda search --info for each package. It's like putting together puzzle pieces. Here's a way to do it using a Python script:

First, you run conda list and save the output. Then, you extract the package names and versions from that output. After that, you iterate over the packages and run conda search --info for each one. This gives you detailed information.

Next, you use some fancy pattern matching (with regular expressions) to find the author and license in the conda search --info output. Once you have that information, you can print or store it as needed.

It's not the most straightforward solution, but it gets the job done. Just keep in mind that if the output format of conda changes, this method might need adjustments.

```
import subprocess
import re

# Get the output of `conda list`
conda_list_output = subprocess.check_output(['conda', 'list']).decode('utf-8')

# Extract package names and versions from the `conda list` output
packages = re.findall(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)', conda_list_output, flags=re.MULTILINE)

# Iterate over the packages and retrieve their detailed information
for package, version in packages[2:]:
    print(package, version)
    conda_search_output = subprocess.check_output(['conda', 'search', '--info', f'{package}={version}']).decode('utf-8')
    # Extract the relevant information from the `conda search --info` output
    package_info = re.search(rf'^{package}\s+{version}.*?license\s+:\s+(.*?)\s+.*?home\s+:\s+(.*?)\s+', conda_search_output, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    if package_info:
        license = package_info.group(1)
        home_page = package_info.group(2)
        # Print or store the information as needed
        print(f'Package: {package} {version}')
        print(f'License: {license}')
        print(f'Home Page: {home_page}')
        print('---')
```

Comment: FYI: `conda` itself is a Python module. Rather than running its entrypoint as a subprocess and parsing stdout, considering using `import conda` and use its functions directly to gather this info. (that script would need to run in **base** environment but it could be used to analyze any environment)